# Python _socket.socket vs socket._socketobject, how to convert from one to the other

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I realised that my problem with wrapping sockets in `ssl`, when the socket is built from a `fd` is related to a `socket._socketobject` being converted (after rebuilding it from `fd`) into a `socket._socket`.

Is there any way to turn the socket._socket back into a `_socketobject`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that actually works was found in a lonely post here: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t557014-socket-vs-_socketobject.html

To get a `socket._socketobject` from a `socket._socket` you need to do:

```
newSockObj = socket.socket(_sock=sock)
```

Ugly, but it works, as that post said...